# maven-jar-plugin adding current directory as dot(.) before the classpath prefix

Tags: java, maven, build

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2</version>
<configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>./lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.test.MyServer</mainClass>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
```

- Want like this Class-Path: . ./lib/spring-2.0.2.jar
- Currently it is like this Class-Path: ./lib/spring-2.0.2.jar

how to add the dot(.) before classpathprefix using maven-jar-plugin, any help much appreciated?

lib
Myjar.jar

i want my manifest Class-Path:  to specify jars in lib folder.

Comment: What kind of project are you working on? Spring Boot?

Comment: no, i just put one sample jar.

Comment: Why is classpath prefix configured ? You don't need that... The mainClass implies that you want to have an executable jar? If so better use maven-shade-plugin or maven-assembly-plugin to create such jar which includes the dependencies....